# Run useEffect when ref.current is assigned a value

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect, ag-grid-react

I have a parent component that has a child component to which I am forwarding a ref via props. The child component contains an ag-grid component which gives me an api which I am sending up to the parent component via forwarded ref like so:

```
import React, { useRef } from "react";
import { AgGridReact } from "ag-grid-react";

function Parent() {
  const defaultFilter = {
    transactionId: {
      filterType: "number",
      type: "equals",
      filter: 1111
    }
  }

  const gridApi = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    gridApi.current.setFilterModel(defaultFilter); // <== throws error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'setFilterModel' of undefined
  }, [])

  return (
    <div>
      <MyGrid forwardedRef={gridApi} />
    </div>
  );
}

function MyGrid(props) {
  const gridApi = useRef();

  const onGridReady = params => {
    gridApi.current = params.api;

    if (props.forwardedRef) {
      props.forwardedRef.current = params.api; // <== send grid's api to parent ref
    }

    ...
  };

  ...

  return (
    <div>
      <AgGridReact
        reactNext={true}
        onCellValueChanged={onCellValueChanged}
        onGridReady={onGridReady}
        columnDefs={columnDefs}
        pagination={true}
        context={ref}
        onSelectionChanged={onRowSelect}
        {...options}
      ></AgGridReact>
    </div>
  );
}
```

There was lot of code so I have omitted some of it to focus on the issue.

Now, as you can see in the code above I am trying to set Filter for `ag-grid` in `Child` component. I want to set the filter as soon as the component is mounted on the page. But it is throwing an error that `gridApi.current` within `useEffect` is `undefined`.

How do I fix this issue?

Comment: Why don't you pass `defaultFilter` as a prop to `MyGrid` and set filter model in child ?

Comment: @aquinq I know about `defaultFilter` but can't use it. actually `Parent` component has some external filters like a dropdown which also updates the `filterModel` and my `server-data-source` is coded in a way that I can use either `defaultFilter` and `externalFilters`. In my scenario I kind of need to merge the defaultFilters with users' external filters, which is why I am using this approach.

Comment: Ok, in this case maybe just checking that `gridApi.current` is not `undefined` before calling `setFilterModel` might be enough ?

Comment: I did try that, didn't work. Filter is never applied.

Comment: That's because your effect dependencies list is empty (second argument of `useEffect`), I just posted an answer for it.

Comment: Does my answer solve your problem ?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to wait for onGridReady before you can call `gridApi.current.setFilterModel(defaultFilter)`. Then only you will have non-undefined `gridApi.current`.
So, instead of running `gridApi.current.setFilterModel(defaultFilter);` inside an useEffect, rut it in a callback in `Parent` and pass that callback to child `MyGrid`

Example code:-

```
function Parent() {
  const defaultFilter = {
    transactionId: {
      filterType: "number",
      type: "equals",
      filter: 1111
    }
  }

  const gridApi = useRef();

  const setParentFilterModel = () => { // <== callback function to be called on onGridReady
    gridApi.current.setFilterModel(defaultFilter); 
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <MyGrid forwardedRef={gridApi} setParentFilterModel={setParentFilterModel}/> {/* <== pass callback function  to child */}
    </div>
  );
}

function MyGrid(props) {
  const gridApi = useRef();

  const onGridReady = params => {
    gridApi.current = params.api;

    if (props.forwardedRef) {
      props.forwardedRef.current = params.api; 
      props.setParentFilterModel() // <== call callback function
    }

  };
}
```